# aurelia-validatejs: @required decorator isn't working, fluent syntax isn't run automatically

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I have set up validation like this:

```
_setValidation() {
    this._validator = new Validator(this.model)
        .ensure("city")
            .required()
            .length({ minimum: 5, maximum: 200 })
        .ensure("emailAddress")
            .required()
            .email();

    // for some reason reporter cannot be named _reporter...
    this.reporter = ValidationEngine.getValidationReporter(this.model);
    this._subscriber = this.reporter.subscribe(result => this._renderErrors(result));
}

_renderErrors(result) {
    this.validationErrors.splice(0, this.validationErrors.length);

    result.forEach(error => {
        this.validationErrors.push(error);
    });
}
```

And the view looks like this:

```
<form class="bordered" submit.delegate="searchRestaurants()">
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
            <label for="email" class="form-control-label">Email address</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" value.bind="model.emailAddress & validate" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <small class="text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
            <br />
            <small class="text-muted">Entered email will be used later on to confirm reservation.</small>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-xs-2 text-right">
            <label for="city" class="form-control-label">City</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-5">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City in which you are looking for a restaurant" value.bind="model.city & validate" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Search for restaurants!" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The problem is that validation isn't run until I press the submit button. This was not the case if I used decorator syntax on my model, like that:

```
export class RestaurantSearchModel {
    @required @length({ minimum: 5, maximum: 200 }) city;
    @required @email emailAddress;
}
```

However in this case there was another problem - the `@required` validator was not being run (ever!).
What can I do to make any of these two approaches work?

PS. I'm using version 0.3.0 of aurelia-validatejs plugin.

**EDIT:**

I updated the plugin to latest version (0.4.0), but it still has some bugs... It seems it's unstable AF! :) So now the purpose of this question changes - are any of you aware of any other aurelia validation plugin?

Comment: The problem with required is a bug https://github.com/aurelia/validatejs/issues/54 and a short term fix https://github.com/aurelia/validatejs/issues/71 and I would suspect the lack of an automatic updates for fluent is too, just not sure of the issue...